# $P(A' ∩ B) = P(B) − P(A)$ when $A \subset B$

Tags: statistics

$A \subset B$. I need to prove that $P(A' ∩ B) = P(B) − P(A)$. I know that I have to use the partition theorem. I have that $P(A' ∩ B) + P(A ∩ B) = P(B)$. But that is all I have. I do not know how to get the $P(A)$. Can someone help me out.

Comment: In your case: $A\cap B=A$ as $A\subset B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the fact that

\begin{align}
B&=A~\cup~(B\setminus A)\\&=A~\cup~(B~\cap~A').
\end{align}

This union is a disjoint union.

Comment: Sorry disregard what I wrote. I read too fast and mixed up the Ps and the sets.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A\subset B$, we have that $B=A\cup(A'\cap B)$. This is the union of disjoint sets and therefore
$$
P(B)=P(A)+P(A'\cap B).
$$